# Find algorithm to base 2 of number without math module

Tags: python, python-3.x, logarithm

What is the most efficient way to find the logarithm to base 2 of a given number without using `math` module?

`math.log` and `math.log2` are float operations therefore have inherent accuracy problems and may give false results, but they are very fast.

The number is guaranteed to be a power of 2, the function will only be executed if the following function returns `True`:

```py
def power_of_2(n):
    return (n & (n-1) == 0) and n != 0
```

I want the result to be 100% accurate and I have already found a way to achieve this:

```py
def log2(n):
    i = 0
    while n > 1:
        n >>= 1
        i += 1
    return i
```

performance:

```
In [244]: def log2(n):
     ...:     i = 0
     ...:     while n > 1:
     ...:         n >>= 1
     ...:         i += 1
     ...:     return i

In [245]: log2(33554432)
Out[245]: 25

In [246]: import math

In [247]: math.log2(33554432)
Out[247]: 25.0

In [248]: %timeit log2(33554432)
2.37 µs ± 208 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

In [249]: %timeit math.log2(33554432)
125 ns ± 1.34 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
```

I found bit manipulation more suitable than float operations for this task, how can I improve the performance of the function while using the same logic?

Comment: You can find the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13211137/get-logarithm-without-math-log-python

Comment: @I_Al-thamary Are you sure "the most efficient way" is there?

Comment: `n >>= 1` is equal to `n //= 2`, so you're basically divide number until it becomes zero. If you're sure that number is power of two, you may use next "hack" `return n.bit_length() - 1`. It works, because in binary representation any power of 2 is `1` with certain amount of `0` in the tail. `2⁰ = 0b1`, `2¹ = 0b10`. `2² = 0b100`, ... , `2¹⁰ = 0b10000000000`, ...

Comment: The accuracy is *not* superior; 2^25 = 33554432

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have tried to run most of the methods from different answers from [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13211137/get-logarithm-without-math-log-python) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13105875/compute-fast-log-base-2-ceiling-in-python) where I found that `power_of_2` and `easy` show a good performance.

```
import math
import timeit

def myLog(x, b):
    if x < b:
        return 0
    return 1 + float(myLog(x / b, b))


def easy(x):
    return x.bit_length() - 1


def brute(x):
    # determine max p such that 2^p <= x
    p = 0
    while 2 ** p <= x:
        p += 1
    return p - 1


def log2_approx(val):
    from math import floor
    val = floor(val)
    approx = 0
    while val != 0:
        val &= ~ (1 << approx)
        approx += 1
    return approx


def log2(n):
    i = 0
    while n > 1:
        n >>= 1
        i += 1
    return i


def power_of_2(n):
    return (n & (n - 1) == 0) and n != 0

def log2_fast(n):
    return  math.frexp(33554436)[1] - 1
import time
from functools import partial
 
import time

start_time = time.time()
math.log2(33554432)
print("math.log2 is %s microseconds ---" % ((time.time() - start_time) * 1000000))
start_time = time.time()
myLog(33554432.0, 2.0)
print(" myLog is %s microseconds ---" % ((time.time() - start_time) * 1000000))

start_time = time.time()
brute(33554432)
print(" brute is --- %s microseconds ---" % ((time.time() - start_time) * 1000000))
start_time = time.time()

log2_approx(33554432) - 1
print("log2_approx is --- %s microseconds ---" % ((time.time() - start_time) * 1000000))
start_time = time.time()
log2_fast = math.frexp(33554436)[1] - 1
print(" log2_fast is --- %s microseconds ---" % ((time.time() - start_time) * 1000000))

start_time = time.time()
log2(33554432)
print("log2 is --- %s microseconds ---" % ((time.time() - start_time) * 1000000))

start_time = time.time()
power_of_2(33554432)
print("power_of_2 is --- %s microseconds ---" % ((time.time() - start_time) * 1000000))
start_time = time.time()
easy(33554432)
print("easy is --- %s microseconds ---" % ((time.time() - start_time) * 1000000))
```

Running time

```
 math.log2 is 3.0994415283203125 microseconds ---
 myLog is 5.4836273193359375 microseconds ---
 brute is --- 6.4373016357421875 microseconds ---
 log2_approx is --- 6.4373016357421875 microseconds ---
 log2_fast is --- 1.6689300537109375 microseconds ---
 log2 is --- 2.1457672119140625 microseconds ---
 power_of_2 is --- 0.7152557373046875 microseconds ---
 easy is --- 0.476837158203125 microseconds ---
```

Using `timeit` shows delay

```
test_items=33554432
base=2
times = timeit.Timer(partial(math.log2, test_items))
print("math.log2 is %s microseconds ---", (times.timeit(1000000)))
times = timeit.Timer(partial(myLog, test_items,base))
print("myLog is %s microseconds ---", (times.timeit(1000000)))
times = timeit.Timer(partial(easy, test_items))
print("easy is %s microseconds ---", (times.timeit(1000000)))
times = timeit.Timer(partial(brute, test_items))
print("brute is %s microseconds ---", (times.timeit(1000000)))
times = timeit.Timer(partial(log2_approx, test_items))
print("log2_approx is %s microseconds ---", (times.timeit(1000000)))
times = timeit.Timer(partial(log2, test_items))
print("log2 is %s microseconds ---", (times.timeit(1000000)))
times = timeit.Timer(partial(power_of_2, test_items))
print("power_of_2 is %s microseconds ---", (times.timeit(1000000)))
times = timeit.Timer(partial(log2_fast, test_items))
print("log2_fast is %s microseconds ---", (times.timeit(1000000)))
```

Running time

```
math.log2 is %s microseconds --- 0.05126429593656212
myLog is %s microseconds --- 4.137887543998659
easy is %s microseconds --- 0.10356121498625726
brute is %s microseconds --- 5.254867412033491
log2_approx is %s microseconds --- 3.81522585300263
log2 is %s microseconds --- 1.7966924259671941
power_of_2 is %s microseconds --- 0.1572157460032031
log2_fast is %s microseconds --- 0.21886748599354178
```

Comment: `easy()` shows a better results because it is the only "native" approach ([look](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/bb3e0c240bc60fe08d332ff5955d54197f79751c/Objects/longobject.c#L5255))

Comment: Benchmarks with single iteration are not representative. Consider using [`timeit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html).

Comment: @I_Al-thamary, benchmarks still require improvements

Answer (score 2):

If your code needs to call this function repeatedly, and the inputs are guaranteed to be even integer powers of two (unlike your example!) I imagine it's going to be hard to beat a hard-coded dictionary lookup.

```py
def precalculate_pow2(ceiling):
    i = 1
    result = dict()
    for n in range(ceiling):
        result[i] = n
        i <<= 1
    return result

powersof2 = precalculate_pow2(500) # or whatever your upper limit is

def log2(n):
    return powersof2[n]
```

Obviously, the loop to calculate the values is no more efficient than your current code, but memoizing it allows you to amortize that cost over all the calls to the `log2` function.

As a variation, you could start with the dictionary containing only one value, and only populate the missing parts on subsequent calls, using a recursive function.

```py
powersof2 = {1: 0}

def log2(n):
    if n not in powersof2:
        powersof2[n] = 1 + log2(n >> 1)
    return powersof2[n]
```

This has the obvious drawback that it will go into an endless loop if you call it with a negative value (though Python will then throw a traceback once you exhaust the maximum recursion limit).

Comment: Can you benchmark against `n.bit_length() - 1`?

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode benchmark function call with dict lookup? Lookup will be faster for sure.

Comment: What benchmark makes sense will depend on the OP's use case. This is basically guaranteed to be slower for a single call, but will break even after a few dozen or so, I imagine.

Comment: Why would the number of calls matter?

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode, because it generates mapping on first "call" and just look for result later,

Comment: I'll grant you that precomputation for free :-). Just benchmark the lookup.

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode, it will be faster. Significantly faster.

Comment: @OlvinRoght Which one? tripleee's? For how long, i.e., until what size? It's rather odd to unconditionally say that an O(log n) solution is faster than an O(1) solution :-)

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode, triplee's solution is `O(1)`, because it's dictionary lookup.

Comment: @OlvinRoght No it's not. Don't forget that lookups need to confirm the hash match with an equality check.

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode so you think that it will take more time than calling stack of function in `bit_length()`? Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1963507/10824407) question and take a look on [`bit_length()` implementation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/bb3e0c240bc60fe08d332ff5955d54197f79751c/Objects/longobject.c#L5255).

Comment: Another variation might be to use `functools.lru_cache()` then there's no need to precalculate a whole load of potentially unused values - you just pay the calculation once on first use.

Comment: @OlvinRoght At `n=2**499` (tripleee's chosen limit), the bit_length solution is already [more than twice as fast](https://tio.run/##ZVHRbsIwDHzPV1hCKE3XbRQ0aUzwJQihUlyI1CZR6gyhad/eOS1r0ZaXpuec7852N7pYs3p3vusqbxsg3aAm0I2znsCjw4KEaJGCgy1IKcUJK3Aey6IuQ10QHpy9LpMSda3NWX0I4KP5bd7fPLahJv496ZIS1WOV9WBAG/CFOeMf6kTa6T3zzIhq2GymthS8uT8Ugi2gb221ZMJ/b2@LhYIZsOr1wuAnerjZ4CE4x9daNzFwK8TMMH0JaQpf@C1iVtHaOpC2puXKrleWo9bO7GU2YOblqOlQoznTJVHwDDlX9twxRj1MUVccMkI4Qet1Bmwwg5xdDiPo1Sr56Eb2Bee1ocS00xjZX2w12pxmaEJz5HTb2JfPiMcFx/7DahNmZjCs94mFsztvO3zUSBuk00TOV6doUMIcEoLXX50Uclyr3hNFR72MyqIz9eBdia77AQ)

Comment: @OlvinRoght And at n=2**5000, it's already about 24 times (!) as fast as the dict lookup. What exactly am I supposed to see in that question about dict lookup complexity and in the bit_length implementation?

Comment: Sounds like you are still measuring a single call, where this very explicitly comes with the caveat that it will be faster only for a program which calls the function repeatedly. If you measure only after the lookup table is generated, I'm pretty sure this will always be faster. What would make sense is a benchmark where you loop over 1, 2, 4, 8, ... and measure at which point the lookup, *including* the overhead, outperforms your alternative.

Comment: @tripleee I *never* measured just a single call. Are you confusing me with the author of the other answer? You can see in the code I linked to that I ran it 100000 times (and did that repeatedly). And that I, as granted earlier, precomputed your table *before* the benchmark. And it still lost. Please do look at the code and results that I linked to.

Comment: I can understand why it could be faster on larger amount. Basically, `bit_length(num)` ends with `sizeof(num) * 8 - __builtin_clz(num)` which is faster than any hash function.

Comment: @OlvinRoght Right, that's another reason that the dict lookup takes O(log n), not O(1). Though to see that one requires looking at the code. And a third reason that the size matters, this time the size of the *limit*, is that [the hash values repeat](https://tio.run/##NYxNCsIwEIX3OcXskpQiRRFEcOVBSgmpHWhmwmS68PQxAft27@d7@asb0@2RpdZVOEHgfY9BkakApsyi8OaDNIoxQQVep3XbUjZ3hWEA9LCyAAISyEKf6O7T5L3pYV/NY7ttUO/bxyVx0TlwSkzOPw00ZUFSZ/vajidkOYRDpNg/3xLFFIv1tf4A) and cause more and more collisions.

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode, thanks for the lesson, not sure was it required though. But I think a disclaimer required, that precomputation is not faster in very rare cases. If your task can't be solved with 5 lines of assembly code, it's a good option.