# Write a function that, given natural numbers n, m, determines the smallest natural number k such that n^k >= m, in time O(log k)

Tags: python

I can do it in only O(k) time can someone be that kind to help me. I can not use build in functions.

```
def potnr(a, b):
    rez = 1
    while b>0:
        if b%2:
            rez = rez * a

        b = b // 2
        a = a * a
        
    return rez

def liczba(n, m):
    k = 1
    while potnr(n, k) < m:
        k += 1

    return k

print(liczba(2, 16))
```

I can do it in only O(k) time can someone be that kind to help me

Comment: First idea that comes to my mind would be to use some dichotomy algorithm: calculate n^2, n^4, n^8 until you pass over m, then track k  between the last 2 powers by dichotomy. I didn't do the actual maths, but I think it should work. Edit: just did some quick mental calculations; if I'm not mistaken, it should be about 2*log2(k).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`n^k >= m` if and only if `k >= log m base n`

Since `log m base n = log m / log n`, this is as simple as:

```
from math import log, ceil
def smallest_k(n, m):
    return ceil(log(m)/log(n))
```

This runs in `O(1)` time.

Comment: FYI: Instead of `log(m)/log(n)`, you can write `log(m, n)`.

Comment: ty for the answer but i can not use build in fuctions sory for not saying that

Comment: Check this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13211137/get-logarithm-without-math-log-python) for manual log without build in functions

Answer (score 1):

This one should work (I just fixed the value of k returned, for there was no guarantee it was the smallest value with the previous return):

```
import math
def min_power(n,m):
    b=1
    while n**b < m:
        b *= 2
    a = b/2
    while b-a > 1:
        c = (a+b)/2
        if n**c < m:
            a = c
        else:
            b = c
    k = math.ceil(a)
    return k if (n**k >= m) else k+1

min_power(35,10**250)
# Out[23]: 162
```

Comment: The question mentions natural numbers, so using non-integers is against the spirit of the challenge. I also suspect you need to check `b±1` before returning `b` just to protect from round-off errors.

Comment: Well about non-integer exponents, it's not a big deal; rounding c would take care of that without impacting the efficiency of the code (I didn't bother to do it for that very reason). As for the return, I totally agree; I rushed the "ending" because I was tired, but I'll fix it right now.

Answer (score 0):

First determine *any* natural number `k` for which `n ^ k >= m`. Then refine your estimate to find the *smallest* such `k`.

It's easiest to find the initial estimate for `k` as a power of 2. Have a temporary value which holds `n ^ k`. Start from `k = 1`, repeatedly multiply `k` by 2, and square your temporary variable, until your `k` is sufficiently big.

Your real `k` will be greater than half the estimate you found. Numbers in that range have `log2(k)` bits. Check each bit, starting from the most significant one. For each such bit, calculate `n ^ k` for two values of `k`: with that bit equal to 0 and 1. Compare with `m` - this will tell you the value of that bit. Proceed to lower-significant bits, until you get to bit 0 (least significant bit).

I am not sure you are allowed to assume that calculating `n ^ k` has O(1) complexity. If not, you have to store intermediate results for all `n ^ k` calculations at first stage, or alternatively, use `sqrt` to calculate lesser powers of `n`.